# Redirect wordpress urls to joomla urls on the same domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect, joomla3.0

this is my first question on stack overflow. This site is bible for me and i hope my question will not be redundant.

Well. I'm creating a news site with joomla 3. My site will replcae and old site made by wordpress. 
Now i'd like to set the redirect rules on the same domain.

On wordpress all news are like this: /ita/news or /eng/news/ 
on my joomla conf: /ita/category/id-news.html /eng/category/id-news.html
The news have the same title and so the same url both on joomla and wp there ia way on htaccess to match the title of the news of the wp links and compare with the last part of the links of my joomla site and set a rewrite condition?

If it not possible my only possibilities is to creare a redirect 301 for all news?
Like this?

Redirect 301 /ita/news /ita/category/id-news.html

Thanks for all
Gabriele

Answer (score 0):

Use `RedirectMatch` to specify a pattern.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /([^/]+)/([^/]+) /$1/category/id-$2.html
```

Using `mod_rewrite` instead, you would be able to restrict the redirection to happen only when the URL path (i.e. the directory structure `/eng/news/`) physically does not exist.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1/category/id-$2.html [R=301,L]
```

This assumes your `.htaccess` resides in the web root folder.

Comment: Ok Thnaks very much for your response! But i'm afraid there is a problem beacuse how can i get teh correct id of my joomla articles evrey time nad the assoicate on the fly with correct urls?

Comment: If you mean the "id" part is a variable and changes for different articles then I'm afraid you would have to manually add all the redirects (like you had planned before) unless this "id" comes as part of the source url somehow so that you can extract it for your rule.